# How to create an "edit" url for a restful resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

In my partial template, there is a varible named "resource", it may be a question or an answer.

I want to build a link to edit it, but when I use it, I don't know what it is, so I can't write:

```
<%=link_to 'edit', edit_question_url(resource)%>
```

or

```
<%=link_to 'edit', edit_answer_url(resource)%>
```

I wonder if there is such a method, say "url_for_edit()", can be used as:

```
<%=link_to 'edit', url_for_edit(resource)%>
```

Is there such a method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try `polymorphic_url(resource)` prefixed with `edit_polymorphic_url(resource)`
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper in ApplicationHelper like this:

```
def edit_question_or_answer_url(resource)
    return edit_question_url(resource) if resource.kind_of? Question
    return edit_answer_url(resource)   if resource.kind_of? Answer
    raise ArgumentError.new "unknown resource: #{resource.class.name}"
end
```

Or by metaprogramming:

```
def edit_question_or_answer_url(resource)
  send "edit_#{resource.class.name.underscore.pluralize}_url".to_sym, resource
end
```

With the first approach the application raises an exception if `resource` isn't valid. In the second the exception is only raised if `resource` isn't a resource

I didn't test this code, but I think is 100% correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: your answer is OK, but is too complicated. `polymorphic_url` is much simpler. Thanks all the same.